# Merge two ext4 spaces

Tags: hard-drive, gparted, merge, storage-spaces

I want to merge `/dev/nvme0n1p6`, which is system linux disk and `/dev/nvme0n1p9`. I have also Windows system on `/dev/nvme0n1p4`, so i want to save it

[image: Here is my sapces]

How can i merge `/dev/nvme0n1p6` with `/dev/nvme0n1p9` without losing my Windows system?

Comment: And what's your question?

Comment: @mtak I want to merge `/dev/nvme0n1p6` with `/dev/nvme0n1p9`. But i cant do it

Comment: "I can't do it" is a statement... Questions, in English at least, end with a `?`. So something like "How can I merge these two partitions without losing my Windows system?"

Comment: So, how can I merge these two partitions without losing my Windows system? @mtak

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot merge these two partitions together.

It might be possible to merge them, if they were right next to each other (delete both or enlarge the first); but the way you have partitioned your disk makes it impossible to merge or combine them.

Not the answer you wanted, but the answer nonetheless.